# Counting Amharic characters in encoded messages within Jasmin sms gateway

Tags: sms, gateway, jasmin

I need help counting the number of characters in Amharic language messages sent through the Jasmin SMS Gateway. Unfortunately, I can only find these messages encoded in the message.log file.

Specifically, I'm looking for:

Method to decode the encoded messages within the message.log file to plain Amharic text.
Function or script within Jasmin that can calculate the character count for Amharic text.
Any alternative approaches or known community solutions for this challenge.